# Turn on Different First Page in MS Word via OOXML or Office-JS

Tags: ms-word, openxml, office-js, word-addins

Seeing that I(or a user) have to manually go to check "Different First Page" in MS Word ever time I open a document, I wonder if there's a way I can include a command in the word-addins to conveniently check the "Different Fist Page" option? Or if this can be done in OOXML (via something like insertOoxml())? I think this is probably doable in VBA macro, but does Word-JS API have anything like setDifferentFirstPage()? or have it done in XML? Thanks!